# Add Extra Parse Log In Field

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift3

I am making an app that logs you in to a certain group, Currently I have it where you log in as such:

```
    let loginUser = PFUser()

    loginUser.username = username.text!
    loginUser.password = password.text!


    PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: loginUser.username!, password: loginUser.password!, block: { (user, error) in

        if user != nil { //Continue with code
```

but what I'd like to do would be to add in my group login ID field so that I do not have to make an additional call to match their groupID TextField with their currently set up groupID. I don't know if you can and I couldn't find it in documentation. Something Like:?

```
    let loginUser = PFUser()

    loginUser.username = username.text!
    loginUser.password = password.text!
    loginUser["groupID"] = groupID.text!

    PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: loginUser.username!, password: loginUser.password!, login["groupID"]: login.groupID block: { (user, error) in

        if user != nil { //Now Checks login AND for group id...
```

Now obviously I know it's not that easy but does anybody have a mildly easy work around for this? Right now afterwords i'm comparing the

```
user["groupID"] == groupID.text! {

// Then Login to group is a success!        
// Segue to next View Controller

} else {

// Let the user know the Log In was "unsuccessful" even though they logged in but they got their groupID wrong
// Log User Out
// Clear groupID Text Field & Display alert so they can reattempt log in

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: how can you ask your that enter group_id if you put a group_id auto increment and with some unique identifier then how can user enter it while user log in ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use "cloud code", you might want to create your own login method using some other language like javascript.